# Flask&Pandas: upload a csv as a pandas Dataframe and pass it through views

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am starting to build an app that allows the user to upload a csv. Then, the csv will be loaded as a Pandas Dataframe. With that dataframe, several calculations will be done, sometimes prompting the user through the process.

I managed to build the uploading process and save the file using the [Flask tutorial.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/) However, I don't know how to pass the Dataframe around from one view to another.

My idea was to perform the calculations on a Dataframe like i would do with a local script, assigning the variable df to the dataframe and referencing it in each view.

Is that possible with Flask? If not, is there any other way to reference a in memory file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is save your data in global variable (dictionary with username as key for example):

```
data = dict() # or another cache structure
def edit(request):
    data[request.user] = your_data
    ...
def save(request):
    your_data = data.get(request.user)
    ...
```

Comment: hmm.. where should i define this dict? This was my initial approach, but when I load the dict in another view is still empty like when I created it :(

Comment: hmmm... in django it works)) Try to use [cache](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/caching/?highlight=cache#) - it will differ from dict only in definition and .set method

Comment: hmm, that looks promising. Do you think this would work in Google App Engine?

Comment: What you are looking for is called cache(or memcache) in all frameworks - very fast method to share your temporary data between some views. In GAE it's represented as follows: [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache)

Comment: and flask has an easy tutorial about this. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. It seems that [caching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/caching/) is the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Flask has a global variable `g` which can be used to arbitrarily attach attributes to.  [See the documentation on it here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#application-globals).

Borrowing Andre's snippet as an example:

```
import flask
def edit(request):
    flask.g.data = your_data
    ...
def save(request):
    your_data = flask.g.data
    ...
```

You can make `flask.g.data` be a dict so long as you add the appropriate logic to know if the dict exists already.  If you were to initialize `flask.g.data = dict()` in your code, then I think `data` would get reinitialized every time your code was called.